# Error with explode and in_array in php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I would like to check the following condition with php

```
$string = '10-15~15-20~20-25~';

    $stringArray = explode('~',rtrim($string,'~'));

    if (in_array('20-25', $stringArray)) {
       echo 'Found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not found';
    }
```

20-25 is present in my array but, it always shows `not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. 
Here is a corrected version.

```
$string = '10-15~15-20~20-25~';
$stringArray = explode('~',rtrim($string,'~')); // corrected here, missing "$" before "string"
if (in_array('20-25', $stringArray)) { // corrected here, wrong variable name "priceArray"
   echo 'Found';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$priceArray` with `$stringArray`. It's just a typo. You are searching "20-25" in non-initialized variable.